# ODE with non standard initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have the following ODE:

\begin{equation}
f'(x) = \frac{a}{x}f(x)
\end{equation}

where $a$ is a constant, $x \in [0,1]$.

With the following initial condition:

\begin{equation}
f'(1) = 0
\end{equation}

If I integrate both sides:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = c\cdot x^{a}
\end{equation}

However, this initial condition is implying that $a = 0$ and $f(x) = c$. Which means that $f'(x) = 0$ $\forall$ $\in$ $[0,1]$. But that cannot be true in my model.

Is there any other solution to this problem? Or it must be this one?

Comment: After integration, the limits on $x$ will lead you to an $\infty$. This can also be seen by the ODE itself. If $x \in [0,1]$, what is $f'(x)$ at $x=0$? Something funny is going on, either with the initial condition or the ODE itself.

Comment: @JacobCheverie I just noticed that $f'(x)$ at $x=0$ is problematic also. This ode follows from a pde which I Fourier Transformed on $y$. It happens that $f'(x)$ at $x=0$ should be the fourier transform on $y$ of $y + bx$, which cannot be Fourier Transformed since it does not converge. I don't know what is going on generally...

Comment: Try sharing the PDE to get some help on the Fourier transform if necessary.

Comment: @JacobCheverie it is this one: $aU(y,x) = bxU_{x} + cU_{yy}$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, $x \in [0,1]$, and $y$ is real.  Also, $U_{x}(y,x=1) = 0$ and $U_{x}(y,x=0) = dy + ex$, where $d$, and $e$ are constants.